# Transpose columns Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

We have an oracle table in the below structure.

[image]

The requirement is to create a sql to generate report in the below format.
As you can see, the last 6 months exposure should get transpose to rows.
There might be cases where we have a year and month data missing as well which needs to be handled.
Appreciate if you check and suggest.

[image]

Thanks,
Pradeep.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()` . . . with window functions to get the last row:

```
select pa.*
from (select pa.*,
             lag(exposure, 1) over (partition by dealid order by rundate) as exposure_1,
             lag(exposure, 2) over (partition by dealid order by rundate) as exposure_2,
             lag(exposure, 3) over (partition by dealid order by rundate) as exposure_3,
             lag(exposure, 4) over (partition by dealid order by rundate) as exposure_4,
             lag(exposure, 5) over (partition by dealid order by rundate) as exposure_5,
             row_number() over (partition by dealid order by rundate desc) as seqnum
      from poolagreements pa
     ) pa
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your suggestion. I tried the below without any luck.. Getting ORA-00933 error. Can you check and suggest?
select t.*
from (select t.*,
lag(exposure, 1) over (partition by dealid order by rundate) as exposure_1,
lag(exposure, 2) over (partition by dealid order by rundate) as exposure_2,
row_number() over (partition by dealid order by rundate desc) as seqnum
from poolagreements t )
poolagreements t
where seqnum = 1;

Comment: @Prdp . . . The table name should be in the *question*.  Assuming it is `poolagreements`, I updated the answer.